# How to search product in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a search functionality in Django, I have some data store in my Django table and i am searching product `name`, but I am getting blank output, Please check my code and let me know where I am Mistaking.

Here is my `urls.py` file:

```py
from .views import SearchResultsView

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('search', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
]
```

here is my `views.py` file:

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Q


class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'mainpage/search-product.html'
    #prod=Product.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        products=Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
        return products
```

here is my `base.html` file:

```html
<form action="/search" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Search a Product">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

here is my `models.py` file:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    subcategory=models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', related_name='prosubcat', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    totalprice=models.IntegerField()
    saleprice = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    description = models.TextField()
    overview = models.TextField(null=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    image= models.ImageField(blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

here is my `search-product.html` file:

```html
<div class="row margin-res">
    {% for catproduct in products %}
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-6 col-grid-box">
        <div class="product-box">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <div class="front">
                    <a href="/product/{{catproduct.slug}}" class="bg-size blur-up lazyload" style="background-image: url(&quot;../assets/images/pro3/1.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; display: block;"><img src="/media/{{catproduct.image}}" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt="" style="display: none;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <a href="/product/{{catproduct.slug}}" class="bg-size blur-up lazyload" style="background-image: url(&quot;../assets/images/pro3/2.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; display: block;"><img src="/media/{{catproduct.image}}" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt="" style="display: none;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info cart-wrap">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addtocart" title="Add to cart"><i class="ti-shopping-cart"></i></button> <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="ti-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-view" title="Quick View"><i class="ti-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="compare.html" title="Compare"><i class="ti-reload" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-detail">
                <div class="rating"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="/product/{{catproduct.slug}}">
                    <h6>{{catproduct.name}}</h6>
                </a>
                <p>{{catproduct.overview}}
                </p>
                <h4>₹ {{catproduct.saleprice}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your templates `mainpage/search-product.html` and models as well please?

Comment: are you sure that the `products.count()` is a ***non-zero value***?

Comment: @ruddra I updated my question, please check `models.py` file there

Comment: @ArakkalAbu could you please update the code for search product in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are missing an attribute in Class named [`context_object_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name) which should have been set to `products`. Try like this:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'mainpage/search-product.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        products=Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
        return products
```

If you do not set this value, then the `context_object` which contains the queryset in template is named `<model name>_list`. More details can be found on how this is defined can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name).

Comment: Thank you so much @ruddra, you saved my day, I was stuck in this from yesterday,